# Capturing clicks on all A tags using eventListener

Tags: javascript, event-handling, event-listener

I'm trying to come up with a solution that will allow me to know whenever an "A" tag (or any other tag within an "A" tag) is clicked.

For example:

```
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a>
<a href="#"><img src="#">Link 3</img></a>
```

So far I have this:

```
<script>
document.getElementsByTagName("BODY")[0].addEventListener('click', function(e) {
if(e.target && e.target.tagName == "A") {
console.log(e.target.text); }
}, false);
</script>
```

This is returning the text for link 1, but not for links 2 and 3. I also do not want to get any text if someone clicks on span or img elements that dont have an anchor tag.

Answer (score 8):

### Legacy Browsers

[`.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target) returns the element that was clicked on. In the case of link 2, this will always be the `span` tag; on a properly formed version of link 3 sometimes it would be the `a` tag, sometimes it would be the `img` tag depending where you click. In order to figure out if the `.target` is inside of an `a` tag you need to climb up the DOM tree using [`parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.parentNode) until you reach an `a` node or the document itself, which has a `.parentNode` of `null`.

```js
var getParentAnchor = function (element) {
  while (element !== null) {
    if (element.tagName && element.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
      return element;
    }
    element = element.parentNode;
  }
  return null;
};

document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var anchor = getParentAnchor(e.target);
  if(anchor !== null) {
    console.log(anchor.textContent);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a>
<a href="#"><img src="example.jpg">Link 3</a>
<div>
Non link text
</div>
```

The standard [`.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) should be preffered over `.text`.

It's easier to use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector) to grab the body, unless you need to support IE7 or less.

### Modern Browsers

If you don't need to support [older browsers like IE or Opera mini](http://caniuse.com/#search=closest), the code can be simplified by using the [`Element.closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) method. You can completely get rid of the `getParentAnchor` and replace it with a single `.closest` call, shortening the code quite a bit:

```js
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var anchor = e.target.closest('a');
  if(anchor !== null) {
    console.log(anchor.textContent);
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<a href="#">Link 1</a>
<a href="#"><span>Link 2</span></a>
<a href="#"><img src="example.jpg">Link 3</a>
<div>
Non link text
</div>
```

Comment: element.tagName is undefined for when while loop reaches at document. This occurs in case of the click e.target doesn't have parent anchor. Here is the updated version:

Comment: `var getParentAnchor = function (element) {
    
      while (element !== null && !(element instanceof HTMLDocument)) {
        console.log(element);
        if (element.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A") {
          return element;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
      }
      return null;
    };`

Comment: @Zahid Thanks for mentioning the bug, I don't know how I missed your comment earlier. I took a different approach to patching it. Since calling the `toUpperCase` method of the non-existent `element.tagName` property was causing the problem, I test for the existence of `tagName` before calling its method, `if (element.tagName && element.tagName.toUpperCase() === "A")`.

Comment: Please note that attaching an event listener to document.body only works for those events that "bubble up" the DOM tree.  For example, mouseover and mouseout are such events, but mouseenter and mouseleave do not bubble out, so event.target will always be document.body.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseenter_event#usage_notes for the explanation for the difference between mouseenter and mouseover.

Answer (score 1):

```
[].forEach.call(document.getElementsByTagName("a"),function(el){
  el.addEventListener("click",function(e){
    console.log(el.text);
  });
});
```

This code will just do the work for you. This will give attach click event to all the a tags. You can el.text to target text inside a.

Comment: Adding a separate event handler to each anchor on the page is extremely inefficient. If the page has a lot of links on it that could add a lot of unnecessary overhead. Event delegation is much more suitable for this situation.

Comment: Moreover, it does not reflect changes in the DOM tree: meaning that newly & **dynamically created <a> tags wouldn’t benefit from this.**